# How to create a vocabulary from a text file using bash?

Tags: bash

I am completely new to bash and am trying to practice with various simple tasks. If given a text file, how can I output the words in the file with their frequencies? For example if the text file contained "I really really love burgers" the output should look like:

Burgers 1

I       1

Love    1

Really  2

I am unsure how to even get started. How do you load text files into bash? And how do you put things? Sorry for the very beginner questions but I would really appreciate some help, thanks!

Comment: Just do `python -c (code in Python)`.

Comment: Seriously,  you can use awk,  perl or something, but if you lready know a convenient scripting language...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want by this way:

1. Take the input text file
2. Take the input Directory to save a file of words in it
3. Print the unique words with their frequencies.

```sh
#!/bin/bash


echo -e "Suggested files: \n"

    ls
    echo -e "\n"

     read -p "Enter the file name :" file

     if [ -e $file ]
     then

        if [ -s $file ]
            then
             echo -e "Enter the directory where do you want to save the file in \n"

             read dir

             words=$(grep -v '^$' $file|tr " " "\n"|sort|uniq)

             grep -v '^$' $file|tr " " "\n" |sort| grep -v '^$' > $dir/file[$j].sorted

             
             for i in $words
             do
                num=$(grep -c "$i" $dir/file[$j].sorted)
                echo -e "The word \e[1;33m$i\e[0m exists \e[1;34m$num\e[0m times in the file \n"
             done 

        else
          echo "The file you have entered is empty"
        fi

    else 
         echo "The file you have entered does not exist"
    fi
```